# Electrical device that can generate a constant amount of steam until the device is switch off

Tags: heat

May I know if such a device exist? The device can generate a constant amount of steam (given water and electricity) until the device is switch off. After switch on, it will generate the steam again.

The expected location of this device will be placed in a room where extreme cold air will surround it. (This is a experience in a lab)

Comment: A kettle? (with thermostat removed) Or one of those [wallpaper stripper](http://www.earlex.co.uk/) things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to BUY one then this is not the place to ask :-).

Sound like fun, but, why do you want steam in a cold lab?

---

Concepts. Made up on spot. Other methods may be better.

1. Kettle with feed tube in via hole such that it stops say 50mm above bottom.
   Feed from feed bottle such that water feeds if level drops.

   Power up kettle for N minutes with timer on demand. Heats and boils. Water self maintains level.
2. As above but fee is into ceramic or Pyrex beaker.
   Use timer to turn on DC ppwer to an eg Nichrome element in water to boil or vaporise water as required.
3. Water dripper is solenoid controlled.
   Water drops fall onto heater element or catridege heater with surface temperature > 100 C when on.
   Enable resistor power and dripper.
   Pish... pish... pish ... Ah!
4. Carpet steamer ...
5. Steam iron with feed ...
6. If you want water vapor and not necessarily STEAM as such then an ultrasonic mister does this very well indeed.

Comment: Definitely I can tell you it is going to be fun but since it is a experiment, I can't tell you other details right now. However, I can confirm with you on one thing - this question is not going to be a shopping or buying recommendation. I like your concepts list - lots of good ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be interested to know why to are trying to do with the device (if you can tell us)

I think Russell covered all the options, so I'll just add a couple of thoughts.

If cost is not too important I would maybe go for a wallpaper stripper as linked to in my comment. We have one of the Earlex devices (sure most other cheap ones are the same) and providing a constant output of steam is exactly what they are designed to do. They have a large water capacity (couple of hours worth IIRC) and a tube for steam output which could easily be adapted for your needs.
I guess a steam cleaner is similar, but I haven't used one (although I'm sure there is one of those around here too...)
So, the pros are, it comes "ready assembled" and with safety valve, plenty of capacity.
Cons are *possibly* more expensive and probably not as easy to source as e.g. a kettle, though I would be quite surprised if there wasn't a few second hand ones on eBay for < £10.

If you want to keep it as cheap as possible (or just don't want to wait for a delivery) then the kettle option would probably be pretty quick and easy to hack together, as long as due precautions were taken with pressure/steam/mains electricity.